# How do i reference external libraries for g++ compiler in command prompt?

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, header-files, libraries

I'm trying to compile and run some C++ code using OpenGL libraries without an IDE using the g++ command in a .bat file.

I have spent some time trying to find the correct syntax for g++ compiling without any luck. I know you are supposed to link the header files for the compiler to create a .o file and then supply the library files to the linker so it can create the executable. The explanations i found about g++ syntax went a bit over my head so i was hoping for a concrete example of how to compile a .cpp file using external libraries.

main.cpp looks like this:

```
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
#include <thread>

int main() 
{ 
glfwInit(); 
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)); 
glfwTerminate(); 
}
```

the full path to glfw3.h is `C:\C++\glfw\include\GLFW\glfw3.h`

The **compilers** .bat file looks like this:

```
@echo off
g++ -std=c++11^
 -I\C:\C++\glfw\include\^
 -c main.cpp^
 -o main.o
pause
```

The **linker** .bat file:

```
@echo off
g++ -L\C:\C++\glfw\lib-mingw\libglfw3.a^
 -L\C:\C++\glfw\lib-mingw\libglfw3dll.a^
 -c main.o^
 -o main.exe
pause
```

I expect the compiler .bat to produce a main.o file which i can later use the linker to make a main.exe file, but instead i get the following error message: 
`main.cpp:1:24: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

Comment: You appear to have an extra `.` in your include path? `-I.\C:\C++\glfw\include\^`

Comment: removing it doesn't change anything, saw some examples where people used `.` after I, but i don't think it matters.

Comment: Maybe you should use `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` instead of `#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"` as using quotes may only search the header file in `main.cpp`'s directory.

Comment: There should be no `\ ` between `-I` and `C:\...` in your "compilers" file. In your "linker" file, pass `C:\C++\glfw\lib-mingw\libglfw3.a` as a regular argument (sans `-L`), remove `-L\C:\C++\glfw\lib-mingw\libglfw3dll.a` entirely, and remove `-c`.

Comment: To be honest, you're better off using an IDE or generating build commands via CMake, rather than wasting time writing batch files to compile your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, found out the problem was with the .dll file for glfw. i deleted libglfw3.a and libglfw3dll.a and put the dll file in both the binary for minGW and in the lib folder. As well as putting the header files directly into the minGW include folder.

Finally i compiled it with the following build command in the VS code IDE:
`g++ "-std=c++17", "-g", "-o", "main","-lopengl32","-lgdi32","-lglu32","-lglfw3","main.cpp"`

Absolutely not an expert and dunno if this is the right thing to do, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If someone compile in windows using cmd …

Compiling:

**g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o -std=c++11 -IC:\C++\glfw\include**

Linking to the static libglfw3.a (don’t put -lglew32s if you don’t use it) :

**g++ main.o -o main.exe -LC:\C++\glfw\lib-mingw\ -lgdi32 -lglfw3 -lglew32s -lopengl32 -lglu32**

Or linking to the dynamic libglfw3dll.a (glfw3.dll must be with the .exe or in c:\windows\system32 or in the path variable):

**g++ main.o -o main.exe -LC:\C++\glfw\lib-mingw\ -lgdi32 -lglfw3dll -lglew32s -lopengl32 -lglu32**

NB. Be sure that the libraries are in C:\C++\glfw\lib-mingw\ and not in another folder like C: \glfw-3.3.6.bin.WIN64\lib-mingw-w64